# How to select states with equal times

Tags: list-manipulation, date-and-time, time-series

Can anyone show me how to select the states that have equal times-dates. For example,
i have two time series. First that have 10 observations, say from 2014/10/1 to 2014/10/10, and second that have 7 observations say from 2014/10/2 to 2014/10/8.Now,I want to select the states from first and second series on equal times-dates. To be more concrete I will write down a exact problem:
Two financial series of stock prices (Period 2007/1/1/ to 2014/10/20):

```
f1 = FinancialData["PA:ACA", "Return", {{2007, 1, 1}, {2014, 10, 20}}];
f2 = FinancialData["PA:AIR", "Return", {{2007, 1, 1}, {2014, 10, 20}}];
```

These series have 2031 and 2019 observations, respectively. I need to select the "states"-returns on the same "Times"-dates in order to estimate the covariance between stock returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f1 = FinancialData["PA:ACA", "Return", {{2007, 1, 1}, {2014, 10, 20}}];
f2 = FinancialData["PA:AIR", "Return", {{2007, 1, 1}, {2014, 10, 20}}];

f3 = Select[GatherBy[Join[f1, f2], First], Length@# == 2 &];
```

Or

```
f3b = Pick[#, Length@# == 2 & /@ #] &@GatherBy[Join[f1, f2], First];

f3 == f3b
(* True *)
```

The first 5 rows of `f1`, `f2` and `f3`:

```
Row[{Labeled[Column@f1[[;; 5]], "f1", Top],
  Labeled[Column@f2[[;; 5]], "f2", Top],
  Labeled[Column@f3[[;; 5]], "f3", Top]}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

Or, to  join the states for each date, you can use

```
    f12 = {#[[1, 1]], #[[1, 2]], #[[2, 2]]}&/@ Select[GatherBy[Join[f1, f2], First], Length@# == 2 &];
Labeled[Column@f12[[;; 5]], "f12", Top]
```

[image]

Comment: Great, Thank You very much.

Comment: @Branimir, my pleasure. Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Please consider visiting the [tour page](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) on the basic rules of the site, the [editing help page](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for editing help and [what should i do when someone answers my question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

In MMA10 this can be done with `TimeSeriesWindow`

**EDIT**

Here base version of `TimeSeriesWindow` for MMA9

```
SelectBetweenDates[financialData_,{startDate_,endDate_}]:=Select[financialData,AbsoluteTime[startDate]<=AbsoluteTime[#[[1]]]<=AbsoluteTime[endDate]&];
SelectBetweenDates[f1,{{2014,10,2},{2014,10,8}}]
(*{{{2014,10,2},-0.0330789},{{2014,10,3},0.0263158},{{2014,10,6},-0.00940171},{{2014,10,7},-0.0163934},{{2014,10,8},-0.0131579}}*)
```

**EDIT2**
Select data between some dates

```
t3 = SelectBetweenDates[f1, {{2014, 10, 2}, {2014, 10, 8}}]~Join~SelectBetweenDates[f2, (*{{2014, 10, 2}, {2014, 10, 8}}];
{{{2014, 10, 2}, -0.0330789}, {{2014, 10, 3}, 
  0.0263158}, {{2014, 10, 6}, -0.00940171}, {{2014, 10, 
   7}, -0.0163934}, {{2014, 10, 8}, -0.0131579}, {{2014, 10, 
   2}, -0.0248523}, {{2014, 10, 3}, 0.0357217}, {{2014, 10, 6}, 
  0.0068576}, {{2014, 10, 7}, -0.026242}, {{2014, 10, 8}, -0.0211891}}*)
```

and then group this data by dates

```
GatherBy[t3, First]
(*{{{{2014,10,2},-0.0330789},{{2014,10,2},-0.0248523}},{{{2014,10,3},0.0263158},{{2014,10,3},0.0357217}},{{{2014,10,6},-0.00940171},{{2014,10,6},0.0068576}},{{{2014,10,7},-0.0163934},{{2014,10,7},-0.026242}},{{{2014,10,8},-0.0131579},{{2014,10,8},-0.0211891}}}*)
```

It's more general approach than proposed by kguler

Comment: Please, add any relevant code and an explanation. As it is currently written it is not a self-contained answer.

Comment: @Branimir try this one

Comment: Please don't start the symbol names with capitals in your answers. It's generally a bad practice as they may collide with future Mma System names.Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. I need one new variable say f3, that will have states form f1 and f2 on the same date. For example, if f1 have 10 observations form 2014/10/1 to 2014/10/10 and f2 have 8 observations in the same period (2014/10/1-2014/10/10), the new f3 variable should select the states from variables f1 and f2 (8 of them) that have same states-dates. This means that if say f2 doesn't have obs. on 6th and 8th October, f3 should have only returns on other dates (1,2,3,4,5,7,9,10) from f1 and all obs. from f2. Form of f3 {{{date}return f1},{{date} return f2}}.